# How do I know which scene has called a particular scene?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a scene where the scores are shown. There are multiple levels and for each level there is a different scene.
I tried this to know which scene called the score scene:

Created a BOOL for every scene and set them to YES in their respective didMoveToView.

Transferred that BOOL value from that scene to the scene being called using NSUserDefaults.

Checked which one was YES using if statements.

But this doesn’t seem to work as expected.
I have an if statement in which it checks which of the different BOOL's value is YES (because only the one from which that scene has been called should be, right? cause no other scene has been called and therefore the value of their respective BOOL is set to NO?) and run that specific code to show the score and the high score like this:

```
if (calledByMED == YES) {
    highScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Best %ld", (long) highScoreMED];

    //[self highScoreLabel];

    NSInteger scoreMED = [prefs integerForKey:@"scoreMED"];

    scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SCORE: %ld",(long) scoreMED];



}

else if (calledByE == YES) {
        highScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Best %ld", (long) highScoreE];

        //[self highScoreLabel];

        NSInteger easyScore =  [prefs integerForKey:@"scoreE"];

        scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long) easyScore];



    }
```

However, it does not do as it should. Suppose if I call the score scene from the "E" scene, the code should skip the calledByMED right?
But, It doesn't. It does what the code in calledByMED says and skips calledByE even though I HAVE called it by E.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you have multiple scenes you should know what scene calls for the high score? Is your high score method a class by itself? Also, why do you have so many scenes in the first place?

Comment: I didn't quite get you. I have a scene for every level.

Comment: The only reason you would have to know what scene is asking for the high score is if the high score method is in a class for itself. Is that the case?

Comment: Nope, that isn't the case. Then how do I do what I am trying to do

Comment: If the high score method is in every scene then just call the part of the method you want. Why have an IF statement if you know what scene is calling the method?

Comment: But the highscores for every scene have to be different. The scenes are the different levels, and each level has its own high score. Therefore, I need to know from which scene the score scene has been called in order to display that particular level's high score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A series of BOOLs is clumsy way to represent a a single property that can be only one thing at at time.  A better representation is a single enum or a string that saves something representing the presenting scene. SKNode has a userData dictionary.  You could use a single key in there:

```
// when presenting a scene:
scene.userData =  [@{ @"fromScene" : @"levelTwo" } mutableCopy];
```

In the score scene:

```
if ([scene.userData[@"fromScene"] isEqualToString:@"levelTwo"]) {}
```

An enum would be quicker and more concise, but then you may want to use a custom attribute, rather than try to wrap the enum (basically an int) into a dictionary.

Comment: glad to hear.  i think the root cause of the original problem was that you'd set one bool when navigating from one level, forget to reset it, then set a different bool on navigation from a different level.  at that point you'd have two bools set, and confusion would follow.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Thanks to you, it is fixed now! :)